# Inferencing with a tf.lite model on 32bit linux

Tags: linux, docker, tensorflow

So I am 400 hours into a project at work building an automated image classification pipeline. I have have overcame many hurdles, and am about finished with the first alpha. Every thing runs in docker containers on my workstation. The only thing left is to build the inference service. So I set up one more docker container pull in my libraries and set up the flask endpoints, and copy the tflite file to the shared volume; every thing seems to be in order, I can hit the API with the chrome and I get the right responses.

So I very happily report that the project is ready for testing 5 weeks early! I explain that all we have to do is install docker, build and run the docker file, and we are ready to go. To this my coworker responds "the target machines are 32bit! no docker!"

Upgrading to 64 bit is off the table.

I tried to compile tensorflow to 32 bit..........

I want to add a single board PC (x64) to the machine network and run the docker from there but management wants a solution that does not require retrofitting.

The target machines have very unstable internet connections managed by other companies in just about every country on earth so a cloud solution is not going to work.(plus I need sub 50 ms latency)

Does anyone have an idea of how to tackle this challenge? at this point I think I am stuck recompiling tf to 32bit; but I don't know how!

The target machines is running a custom in house distro of Debian 6 32bit.
The target machines are old and have outdated software but were very high end at the time they were built.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Ouch, no fun! But this seems off-topic here. Did you look for `tf` specialist forums? Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear which 32bit architecture you want to use. I guess it's ARM32.
If that's the case, you can build TF or TFLite for ARM32.
Check the following links.

- https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source_rpi
- https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/build_rpi

Though they're about RPI, you could get some idea on how to build it for ARM32.